# BeautilulSoup Insert a tag and children of this new tag with associated value

Tags: python-3.x, xml, beautifulsoup

I need to update an XML file. Its structure is

```
<product sku="xyz">
...
  <custom-attributes>
  <custom-attribute name="attrib1">test</custom-attribute>
...
  </custom-attributes>
</product>
```

I want to add a line with a custom-attribute which is multi-valued so the required structure looks like this :

```
<custom-attributes>
  <custom-attribute name="attrib1">test</custom-attribute>
  ...
  <custom-attribute name="new1">
    <value>word1</value>
    <value>word2</value>
    ....
  </custom-attribute>
</custom-attributes>
```

I wrote the following python code

```
precision = {"name" : "new1"}

for sku in soup.find_all('product'):
    tagCustoms = sku.find('custom-attributes')
    mynewtag = soup.new_tag('custom-attribute', attrs = precision)
    tagCustoms.append(mynewtag)
    for word in words:   # words is a list
        mynewtag.insert(1,soup.new_tag('value'))
```

It works ... except I can't find how to define the content within value's tag .. how to assign each word from words 'list within the same loop ?

I am stuck with this result

```
  <custom-attribute name="new1">
    <value></value>
    <value></value>
    ....
  </custom-attribute>
</custom-attributes>
```

I tried this code

```
for sku in soup.find_all('product'):
    tagCustoms = sku.find('custom-attributes')
    mynewtag = soup.new_tag('custom-attribute', attrs = precision)
    tagCustoms.append(mynewtag)
    for word in words:   # words is a list
        mynewtag.insert(1,soup.new_tag('value'))
        mynewtag.value.string = word
```

but it only add the first word of the list the first value tag.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to handle this, but try this one and see if it works.

Change your `for` loop to:

```
for word in words:   
        ntag = soup.new_tag('value')
        ntag.string = word
        mynewtag.insert(1,ntag)
```

Comment: OK I was confused and thought you 'insert' or 'append' had parameters to add this ! Thanks